# How to make text bold and italic when I receive email from an html form with php handler

Tags: php, html

I want to make "new order!" and "all user input" data in bold when I receive email. Also want to make "Every customer ... company" italic.

```
$to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Order from: $name";
    $email_body = "New order!".
    "\n Below are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Phone Number: $phone_number \n Item Code: $item_code \n Payment Mode: $payment_mode \n Address: $address \n \n Every customer expects quality services from your company";
```

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function has 4 parameters: to, subject, message, and headers.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

To enable HTML messages (which would allow you to use tags like `<strong>` and `<em>` to create bold and italicized texted respectively), simple add the following line into the $headers parameter.

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Headers can also be used to add formatting to the To and From fields, as well as include CC and BCC:

```
$headers = "From: From Name<" . strip_tags($from_email) . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Reply-To Name<". strip_tags($from_email) . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "To: ". strip_tags($to_email) ."\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

*Note: This particular example came from [here](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)
*Also Note: The fourth parameter of the mail() function (*$headers*), is completely optional, but in order to enable HTML email (rather than the default plain text email), you must specify it in the $headers parameter.

Comment: What do you meant by $headers parameter? The php starts with "<?php" and has this code almost at the end "$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
 
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 //redirect to the 'thank you' page
 header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}"

Comment: $headers as in the fourth parameter of the mail() function. This corresponds to the headers that are sent with EMail. You can read more about the PHP Mail function [here](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 1):

use this code for HTML use in PHP mail

```
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: yeah written in the code but its still display error upon submit. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/fyxniokd/public_html/order-handler.php on line 44" "line 44= mail=isHTML(true);"

Comment: Error again on submit the form :(  "Fatal error: Call to a member function IsHTML() on a non-object in /home/fyxniokd/public_html/order-handler.php on line 44"